# Undefined behaviour when entering `char` for integer variable with `std::cin`

Tags: c++

I have this while loop, just to check if the entered number is 2. If the user entered by accident a letter instead of a number the loop goes to infinity even though I've added isdigit, but didn't fix the loop from going crazy if the input is a character. This is code:

```
int num1;
bool cond {false};
while(!cond){
    cout<<"enter 2:";
    cin>>num1;
    if (!isdigit(num1)){
        cout<<"not a digit:";
        cin>>num1;
    }
    //
    if(num1 == 2)
        cond = true;
}
```

Comment: `isdigit` checks whether char is digit, ASCII codes for digits are 48-57, but you do `cin` for int

Comment: You mean you got an error when you input character? `num1` is variable only for integer. it can not read string or character by cin. if you want it, `char num1; cin >> num1;` and then convert it to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying something a little more straightforward instead of your current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int num1;
   cout << "Please enter the number 2:";
   cin >> num1;
   while (num1 != 2)
   {
       cin.clear(); //Clears the error flag on cin. 
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       cout << "You did not enter the number 2, Please try again:";
       cin >> num1;
   }
   
   return 0;

}
```

Now, `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` is when it ignores up until `'\n'` or `EOF` `\n` is the delimiter meaning that, that is the character at which `cin` will stop ignoring.

Furthermore,  `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is basically saying there is no limit to the number of characters to ignore.

You need to use the header file `#include<limits>` to use this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend separating the reading of input data from converting it to a number.  A good method for this is to use stringstream.  Here's a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    string input;
    bool cond{ false };
    cout << "enter 2:";
    while (!cond) {
        getline(cin, input);
        stringstream ss(input);
        ss >> num1;
        if( ss.fail() ){
            cout << "not a digit:";
            continue;
        }
        //
        if (num1 == 2)
            cond = true;
        else
            cout << "enter 2:";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int num1;
bool cond {false};
do{
    cout<<"enter 2:";
    cin>>num1;
    if (cin.good()) {
        cond = true;
    }else {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Invalid, please enter 2." << endl;
    }
}while(!cond);
```

While false, execute statements.  Also, if you want the user to re-enter a number, cin must be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the variable `num1` as char because `isdigit(ch)` works for char and not for int.

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: isdigit actually takes an int as input.  Though your right that it's expected to be a char that's cast as an int.

Comment: yeah, I actually mean that. My poor choice of words :[

Answer (score 0):

## Why does the loop iterate infinitely?

Let's take this example

```cpp
int a;

std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "Entered: " << a;
```

Now  let's test it with different inputs

### with `int`

> 5 
> Entered: 5

> 10 
> Entered: 10

Yes just as we would expect, but what happens when you enter a `char`?

### with `char`

> r 
> Entered: 0

> f 
> Entered: 0

Why does this happen?

When you declare the variable `int`, and then do `std::cin >>` , you are telling the input method that the **user will enter an integer**, but when it doesn't get what it expected, **it will fail**. C++ will not implicitly convert the value of `char` into `int`.  Hence, you get strange results.

## How to solve this?

As I have mentioned earlier, **it fails**. When this fails you can catch it this way

```cpp
if (!(std::cin >> a)) 
{
    std::cout << "Invalid input ! \n";
}
```

We're saying, ***if*** the input fails, show the message.

let's test this new code.

```cpp
int a;
if (!(std::cin >> a))
{
    std::cout << "Invalid input !\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Entered: " << a;
}
```

> 5 
> Entered: 5

> r 
> Invalid input !

### How to print `char` value of the `int`?

If you want to just print the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the entered number, you need to [cast](http://www.eeng.dcu.ie/%7Eee553/ee402notes/html/ch03s08.html) the value into `char`.

You can do

```cpp
int num = 48;
char character_value = num;
```

Here C++ will implicitly convert `char` into `int`.

But if you need a safer type of conversion, prefer using `static_cast<>`.
The syntax looks like this

```cpp
int a = 5;
char character_value = static_cast<char>(a);
```

**[Static cast in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/static-cast-operator?view=vs-2019)** 
**[Type casting in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/)**
**[Dealing with invalid input in C++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/5-10-stdcin-extraction-and-dealing-with-invalid-text-input/)**